# jeditable cancel button callback?

Tags: jquery

the solution here:
[Jeditable CANCEL callback from AJAX callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128760/jeditable-cancel-callback-from-ajax-callback)
using onreset() doesnt seem to work...

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cancel button effectively kicks you from the input field, so you could get a callback out of the blur event.