# Callback for Cancel event for jQuery jEditable

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I an using Mike Tuupola's jQuery jEditable as follows:

```
function wireupTagCategoryInPlaceEditing() {

    $('.category-label').editable(submitTagCategoryEdit, {
        event: 'tagcategoryedit', // conditionally triggered in wireupTagCategoryClick()
        type: 'text',
        submit: '&nbsp;Ok&nbsp;',
        cancel: 'Cancel',
        cssclass: 'tagcategory-inplace-edit'
    });

} 

function submitTagCategoryEdit(value, settings) {
    //handle the edit 
}
```

I need to intercept the cancel event - what is the best way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607404/jeditable-cancel-button-callback) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128760/jeditable-cancel-callback-from-ajax-callback)

```
$("#editable_text").editable(submitEdit, { 
    //...
    onreset: jeditableReset,
    //...
});

function jeditableReset(settings, original) {
   // whatever you need to do here
}
```